# How do I lift shared variables out of a rust Fn without it becoming a FnOnce?

Tags: rust

I have an example proxy server implemented below, but try as I might I can't figure out how to lift the `client` out of the closure so it can be shared. If I lift it out and remove the `move` then it won't compile because the closure can outlive the lifetime of the `client`. If I keep the move then it's a `FnOnce` instead of a `Fn`. How can I lift the `client` so that it can be shared and increase it's lifetime so that the compiler realizes it's sticking around until the termination of the application?

cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["full"] }
reqwest = { version = "0.10", features = ["json"] }
warp = "0.2.5"
env_logger = "0.8.2"
serde_json = "1.0.61"
futures = "0.3.8"
```

main.rs

```
use serde_json::Value;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use warp::{Filter, http::Method};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    env_logger::init();
    let log = warp::log("webserver::proxy");

    let cors = warp::cors()
        .allow_any_origin()
        .allow_header("content-type")
        .allow_methods(&[Method::GET, Method::POST, Method::DELETE]);

    let signup_route = warp::post()
        .and(warp::path("signup"))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and(warp::body::content_length_limit(1024 * 16))
        .and(warp::body::json())
        .and_then(|body: HashMap<String, Value>| async move {
// How do I move token and client out of this closure to share it?
            let token = std::env::var_os("TOKEN").unwrap().into_string().unwrap();
            let client = reqwest::Client::new();
            return match client.post("https://api.example.com/api")
                    .header("Authorization", &token)
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .json(&body)
                    .send().await {
                Ok(x) => {
                    let status = x.status();
                    let json = x.json::<HashMap<String, Value>>().await;
                    return match json {
                        Ok(j) => Ok(warp::reply::with_status(warp::reply::json(&j), status)),
                        Err(_) => Err(warp::reject()),
                    }
                },
                Err(_) => Err(warp::reject()),
            };
        });

    let option_route = warp::options().map(warp::reply);
    let routes = signup_route.or(option_route).with(cors).with(log);

    warp::serve(routes)
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030))
        .await;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the client and token to `warp` which ships them off to different threads where they could (as far as the compiler is concerned) outlive the values that hold them. This is why the compiler won't allow the closure to capture a reference to `client` and `token` defined outside it.

Instead, you need to heap-allocate those values and move a [reference-counted smart pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) into the closure. That allows you to have your cake and eat it: you have a `move` closure that owns a value, the owned "value" is just a pointer, and you have another copy of the pointer, which you obtain by cloning the `Arc`. A similar transformation must be done for the inner closure, which must become `move` for the same reasons.

```
use serde_json::Value;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Arc;
use warp::{http::Method, Filter};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    env_logger::init();
    let log = warp::log("webserver::proxy");

    let cors = warp::cors()
        .allow_any_origin()
        .allow_header("content-type")
        .allow_methods(&[Method::GET, Method::POST, Method::DELETE]);

    let client = Arc::new(reqwest::Client::new());
    let client_shared = Arc::clone(&client);

    let token = Arc::new(std::env::var_os("TOKEN").unwrap().into_string().unwrap());
    let token_shared = Arc::clone(&token);

    let signup_route = warp::post()
        .and(warp::path("signup"))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and(warp::body::content_length_limit(1024 * 16))
        .and(warp::body::json())
        .and_then(move |body: HashMap<String, Value>| {
            let client_shared = Arc::clone(&client_shared);
            let token_shared = Arc::clone(&token_shared);
            async move {
                return match client_shared
                    .post("https://api.example.com/api")
                    .header("Authorization", token_shared.as_str())
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .json(&body)
                    .send()
                    .await
                {
                    Ok(x) => {
                        let status = x.status();
                        let json = x.json::<HashMap<String, Value>>().await;
                        return match json {
                            Ok(j) => Ok(warp::reply::with_status(warp::reply::json(&j), status)),
                            Err(_) => Err(warp::reject()),
                        };
                    }
                    Err(_) => Err(warp::reject()),
                };
            }
        });

    let option_route = warp::options().map(warp::reply);
    let routes = signup_route.or(option_route).with(cors).with(log);

    warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030)).await;
}
```